# Which character name is displayed in FFXIV?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I am creating my first character for Final Fantasy XIV, and I want to get it right.  Is my forename or my surname displayed above my character?

Comment: Was that edit really necessary? The capitalization was intentional...

Comment: Both of them are. I'm currently behind a firewall at work so I can't give you screenshots, I'm afraid

Comment: @Evorlor: You should be able to rollback the change if you want but the capitalisation is gramatically incorrect. I'm not sure why you wanted it there intentionally really but it didn't do anything for me certainly... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both names are displayed in-game, and both names are required for everything that involves specifying a player's name (for example, sending a /tell, sending a party invite, adding someone to your friends list, etc).

However, through the game settings, each player can choose to cosmetically abbreviate *other players'* names in certain parts of their user interface to reduce visual clutter. The possible choices are:

- Full forename and full surname ("Mike Jones")
- Full forename and first letter of surname ("Mike J.")
- First letter of forename and full surname ("M. Jones")
- Initials ("M. J.")

Answer (score 2):

Both names are displayed.  For example: "Forename Surname".

Also note that it is the combination of the two names that must be unique for your particular server.  Several people may have the same Forename or Surname, but no one can have both the same as you.  So you will never see another character that says "Forename Surname".  (Except possibly in dungeons because you may be paired with a person on a different server.)